# Plugin-enabled SMTP-Server to add filter-functionality

Tags: smtp, email-spam, mail-server

A few days ago, an idea came to my mind regarding a spam-protection technology.

Therefore, I'm in search of an **SMTP-server**, which is able to be enhanced by **filter plugins**.

Is anybody aware of an **SMTP framework or a SMTP-server**, which provides an API for plugins?

I already stumbled upon [Apache's james Project](http://james.apache.org), which at least seems to provide a rich set of email-related modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to [subethasmtp](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/) some days ago and belive that its api support what you are searching for.

You can implement some Handlers, to deal with mails.

```
final MessageHandlerFactory mhf = new MessageHandlerFactory() {

            @Override
            public MessageHandler create(final MessageContext ctx) {
                return new MessageHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void recipient(final String recipient) throws RejectException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void from(final String from) throws RejectException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void done() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void data(final InputStream data) throws RejectException, TooMuchDataException, IOException {
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        final SMTPServer srv = new SMTPServer(mhf);
        srv.start();
```

Comment: Great! Might be the perfect candidate, since the authors focused on extensibility. I'm going to download and compile the solution. Just in case someone proposes another option, I'll keep the question open for a few days. Thank you, Mirko!

Comment: You're welcome! ;) But I use subethasmtp only for mail testing @localhost in our continuous integration system. So I dont have to write Handlers etc.

Comment: SubEthaSMTP comes with no POPe/IMAP support, does it? In this case I need to implement POP3 first...